# Notebook doesn't respond to keyboard/mouse after sleep/hibernate

Tags: 17.10, hibernate

After some time (a few hours after I close the notebook with a running system) Ubuntu does not respond to keyboard/mouse/touchpad, but I can login using ssh from another PC. I have an Nvidia graphics card and Ubuntu 17.10, updated from 16.04.
Same thing on PC (also updated from 16.04 to 17.10).
After restart Ubuntu don't see this crash so this issue will not be fixed quickly. Windows was better about this.